# size p:commanButton with fa-2x

Tags: css, primefaces, font-awesome

My problem is the next:

I have a p:commanButton like this:

```html
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-reply fa-2x"/>
```

The problem is that the content (`fa-reply`) grows but the size of the button doesn't.

Which is the problem?

When I do: `<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-reply" styleClass="fa-2x"/>` the size of the button grows, but the content doesn't show correctly.

Comment: Are you using text with icon?

Comment: The button doesn't has text, but it has tittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, simple work-arround would be to use `p:commandLink` with manual `<i class="fa fa-reply fa-2x"></i>` tag instead of `p:commandButton`, as following:

```
<p:commandLink>
    <i class="fa fa-reply fa-2x"></i>
</p:commandLink>
```

And if you want to use text as well, then:

```
<p:commandLink>
    <i class="fa fa-reply fa-2x"> Reply</i>
</p:commandLink>
```

Otherwise, you will require to add compatencies for the different sizes of the icons (`fa-xx`) on your `p:commandButton` using custom CSS classes.

Comment: This is a workaround in my book, as you are using a different component instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `style="font-size: 2rem"` to your button:

```html
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-reply" style="font-size: 2rem"/>
```

This will set the font size of both the icon and the button text.

Example from the showcase where I applied this to the button in the middle:

[image]

I suggest to create a class though, so you can reuse this style on buttons.

See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)